# My auto increment primary key is not automatically incrementing

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have the following database
[image: attributes structure]

[image]

[image]
Whenever I try inserting values in the database I get the following error.

Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'
This means ID is not incrementing automatically.

I am using the following storage procedure.

```
USE user_db;

DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE `InsertValues`( IN name TEXT(30), IN email VARCHAR(50), IN phone   VARCHAR(100), IN date VARCHAR(15),IN photo VARCHAR(10), IN password VARCHAR(10))

BEGIN
INSERT INTO user_details ( ID,name,email,phone,date,photo,password) VALUES('',name,email,phone,date,photo,password);

END//

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Try removing the `ID` colum/value declaration in your insert or use the `NULL` value instead of `''`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO user_details 
  (ID,name,email,phone,date,photo,password) 
VALUES 
  (NULL,name,email,phone,date,photo,password);
```

Or as @Cristian mentioned, remove `ID` completely from your insert statement.

And you should drop the index on `ID` as it is redundant.